# AttributeError: Entry instance has no attribute '__len__'

Tags: python, tkinter

I am quite new to python, I have been playing around with Tkinter and [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) to try to create a simple program that can log into my web application. I have been getting the following error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1410, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "test.py", line 35, in login
    c.post('http://fruro.com/login.php', data=self.payload)
  File "/Users/Peter/Desktop/fruroPy/fruro/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 399, in post
    return self.request('POST', url, data=data, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/Peter/Desktop/fruroPy/fruro/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 343, in request
    prep = req.prepare()
  File "/Users/Peter/Desktop/fruroPy/fruro/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 222, in prepare
    p.prepare_body(self.data, self.files)
  File "/Users/Peter/Desktop/fruroPy/fruro/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 375, in prepare_body
    body = self._encode_params(data)
  File "/Users/Peter/Desktop/fruroPy/fruro/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 81, in _encode_params
    return urlencode(result, doseq=True)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 1311, in urlencode
    len(v)
AttributeError: Entry instance has no attribute '__len__'
```

I have been trying to figure out what could have gone wrong for several hours but I just don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Here is my code that I'm using:

```
from Tkinter import *
from requests import session

class Login:

    def __init__(self, master):

        frame = Frame(master)
        frame.pack()

        self.emLabel = Label(frame, text="Email:")
        self.emLabel.pack(side=LEFT)

        self.email = Entry(frame, width=15)
        self.email.pack(side=LEFT)

        self.pasLabel = Label(frame, text="Password:")
        self.pasLabel.pack(side=LEFT)

        self.password = Entry(frame, show="*", width=15)
        self.password.pack(side=LEFT)

        self.hi_there = Button(frame, text="Login", command=self.login)
        self.hi_there.pack()

    def login(self):

        self.payload = {
            'action': 'login',
            'email': self.email,
            'password': self.password 
        }

        with session() as c:
            c.post('http://fruro.com/login.php', data=self.payload)
            self.request = c.get('http://fruro.com')
            print self.request.headers
            print self.request.text


root = Tk()
login = Login(root)
root.title("Login to your account")
root.mainloop()
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is on this line,

```
c.post('http://fruro.com/login.php', data=self.payload)
```

And it is happening because the `dict` you are passing in as `data` parameter has values that are references to `Entry` widgets and not the content of those widgets. So when `Requests` tries to get the `len`, you get an error since `Entry` doesn't implement `__len__` (not what you wanted anyway). To fix it change `self.payload` to something like,

```
self.payload = {
        'action': 'login',
        'email': self.email.get(),      # call get method to return
        'password': self.password.get() # the value in the Entry widgets
    }
```