# instance has no attribute '__len__'

Tags: python, attributes

this will be a simple question, so it won't take you much time to explain it to me, but it would help me (and possibly other people too) understand something about classes and methods and Python.

My code wants to represent a board game, at this level just on a board with N holes in a row, which can accommodate marbles numbered from 0 to N-1 (in a random order).

```
class MarblesBoard:
    '''define the board game'''
    def __init__(self, Board):
        self._Board = Board
        self._n = len(Board)

    '''first type of move available: switch the first two marbles'''
    def switch(Board):
        Board[0], Board[1] = Board[1], Board[0]
        return Board

    '''second type of move available: move all the marbles by 1 space to the left'''
    def rotate():
        temp = Board[0]
        for i in range (0, n-1):
            Board[i] = Board[i+1]
        Board[n-1] = temp
        return Board

    '''print the state'''
    def __repr__(Board):
        for i in range(0, len(Board)):
            print self[i],

    '''rest to be developed when this works'''
```

now, I test displaying the board and moving the marbles. So I let

```
First = MarblesBoard([1,2,3,4])
First.rotate
```

and only get

```
<repr(<instancemethod at 0x104230410>) failed: AttributeError: MarblesBoard instance has no attribute '__len__'>
```

I know there has already been a similar question about this error message. 
[AttributeError: Entry instance has no attribute '__len__'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16389356/attributeerror-entry-instance-has-no-attribute-len)

I still somehow don't see how does the same error arise in my code. Would you mind explaining (in general) when is the attribute "**len**" established, and maybe suggest how could it be done in this code?

Comment: You need `def __repr__(self): for i in range(0, len(self._Board)): print i` The `__repr__` method should be within your `Board` class. Further each of the methods `switch`, `rotate` should be defined as `switch(self)`, `rotate(self)` and operate on `self.Board`

Comment: I don't understand why you're trying to access `len` on a class. Shouldn't you be using an instance? Also, shouldn't all the methods in the class be suitably indented from the `class MarblesBoard:` statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def __init__(self, Board):
    self._Board = Board
    self._n = len(Board)

'''first type of move available: switch the first two marbles'''
def switch(Board):
    Board[0], Board[1] = Board[1], Board[0]
    return Board
```

You seem to expect that `Board` in the `switch` method will be the same `Board` as in `__init__` - it isn't. The first argument to any method is the instance you are working with (so, an instance of `MarblesBoard`, when you are expecting it to be a list) - the name you give it doesn't affect that, but it is conventional to (as you have correctly done in `__init__`) call it `self`.

The `Board` in `__init__` is the argument you actually passed in - a list. To get it back in other methods, you need to keep it around attached to `self` - you've done this already, its called `self._Board`. Like any variable name or function argument, the name you choose won't affect the functionality, but - again - there are conventions and calling it `self._board` (all lowercase) instead would be more usual. So, you can rewrite the above two methods as:

```
def __init__(self, board):
    self._board = board
    self._n = len(Board)

'''first type of move available: switch the first two marbles'''
def switch(self):
    self._board[0], self._board[1] = self._board[1], self._board[0]
```

(note you probably *don't* want to return anything from `switch` now that it changes the state of `self`).

This brings us to the heart of the problem. Python is implicitly calling the `__repr__` method, which you have defined like this:

```
def __repr__(Board):
    for i in range(0, len(Board)):
        print self[i],
```

The same thing is going on: you expect `Board` to be a list, when it is a `MarblesBoard`. Calling `len(Board)` then tries to call `MarblesBoard.__len__`, which doesn't exist. You've also tried calling `self[i]` which would also be an error if there hadn't been one just before it (because it calls a different magic method, `MarblesBoard.__getitem__`, which you also haven't defined). The way to fix both problems at once is to do exactly what we did above and get to the list through the `MarblesBoard` instance:

```
def __repr__(self):
    for i in range(0, len(self._board)):
        print self._board[i]
```

Will work. However, note that this formulation still isn't very Pythonic - once your code works, you may want to consider posting it on [codereview.SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Calling `print` within `__repr__` is not how it is supposed to work. You should be **returning** the string.

Comment: @b4hand this is true, but note that that error is directly copied from the question. I deliberately didn't fix all the unconventional things, and instead punt it to codereview, because the answer was already getting a bit unweildy.

Answer (score 1):

When you do:

```
First = MarblesBoard([1,2,3,4])
First.rotate
```

`__repr__` is called, so the representation of the object can be echoed on your terminal. Here is yours (note that printing in it is wrong, you should just return the string, but correcting that is out of scope for this.):

```
def __repr__(Board):
    for i in range(0, len(Board)):
        print self[i],
```

You call `len(Board)`. This argument, `Board` is actually the instance of the object. It is Pythonic to use `self` instead. You have not defined a `__len__` function for `len` to call for this object, and thus you get the error you see.

---

Here's an example of some edits I would make. First inherit from object:

```
class MarblesBoard(object):
    '''define the board game'''
```

Next, we only capitalize class names:

```
    def __init__(self, board):
        self._board = board
        self._n = len(board)
```

Finally, docstrings go beneath the function name and arguments:

```
    def switch(self):
        '''first type of move available: switch the first two marbles'''
        self.board[0], self.board[1] = self.board[1], self.board[0]
        return self.board
```

Comment: Calling `print` within `__repr__` is both dangerous and wrong.

Comment: Thank you, Aaron! Just one last quick question: what is the purpose of defining     class MarblesBoard(object):    ? Can it be used for defining the board array? When I try it, I get a     TypeError: object() takes no parameters

Comment: @LochnessMonster I would take the more simple approach of making the array an attribute of the object, that way you can more easily change the implementation. See the Python data model for more ways of customizing objects ( https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#basic-customization ), but I'd keep it simple while you're learning.